# Spring “prototype” bean scope vs “new” operator

Tags: spring, scope, prototype, javabeans

Can someone explain the difference between Spring “*prototype*” bean scope and using “*new*” operator? Also what is the advantage of declaring the bean with “*prototype*” scope over “*new*” operator?

Answer (score 7):

Prototype beans do mean that a new instance of the bean is created every time it is requested (in which case you might think you may as well be instantiating it yourself when needed using `new`).

But the key thing is that they still satisfy the dependency injection design pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) which among many other things makes unit testing with mocked dependencies significantly easier.

Comment: Are prototype beans garbage collected  the way objects created with new operator are ? I came across a line in spring documentation which says developers are responsible for destroying prototype beans after its requested.

Comment: Since prototype beans are essentially regular Java objects created using the `new` operator, they are subject to the same garbage collection mechanism as other objects created with `new`.